# I can´t open a GeoTiff layer in QGis Lyon

Tags: geotiff-tiff, qgis-2.12

I get a problem.
I have been trying to open a Geotiff layer and Qgis turn off automatically. Then a report appear (bellow). 
I hope someone can help me with it.

```
Dyld Error Message:
Symbol not found: _GTIFAllocDefn
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/GDAL
Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/UnixImageIO.framework/Versions/E/UnixImageIO
```

Comment: Have-you installed the [UnixImageIO_Framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/UnixImageIO_Framework-1.5.1.dmg) ?